# For any given Dom nod find nods that have css style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to get all elements that have specified styles on them.

```
//let's say
 let d = $(document)
```

There is no way to do `d.find` or `d.filter` for all children that have `.css('background-image')`.
The node that has to be searched is always different since it comes from `mutation.target`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you looking for `style` attributes, or styles that are inherited from CSS?

Comment: @Barmar both, any style that has a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selector `*` to find all elements, then use `.filter()` to test `.css()` with the style you want.

```
$(document).find("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-image');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(
    'li[style*="background:red"]'
);

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li style="background:red;">test1</li>
    <li style="background:blue;">test2</li>
    <li style="background:green;">test3</li>
    <li style="background:red;;">test4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to know which element it will be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution that get the elements according it's style property, but every property has it's own structure, for example the background and colore are in `rgb()` structure, I'll give a simple example on width style property:

```js
const elements = $('li').filter(function() {
    return getComputedStyle(this).width == '100px';
});

console.log('elements: ', elements)
```

```css
.width-100 { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li style="background:red;">test1</li>
    <li style="background:red; width:100px">test2</li>
    <li style="background:red;">test3</li>
    <li class="width-100" style="background:red;">test4</li>
</ul>
```